# Basic machine learning

Tags: java, machine-learning

I am developing a tool where I need to predict a the value of a variable based on the combination of a number of variables.

The implementation needs to be in Java programming language.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: no :) i know my question is very abstract... i need an idea to kick start my work...

Comment: I strongly recommend you take a look at Weka (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) - very good machine learning tools based on Java

Comment: Without more details, the advice you'll receive is unlikely to be very useful for your specific task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to begin with something simple, consider a quasi-linear model, such as logistic regression or linear discriminant analysis: they are easy to understand, and there is code for them all over the Internet.  Also consider some of the simpler (single node) neural models (perceptron, delta rule, etc.): they are very easy to program.  If you want to pursue this, I suggest getting a book, such as "Computer Systems That Learn", by Weiss and Kulikowski.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good Stanford Open Course about machine learning with video lectures etc.
Take a look [here](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=348ca38a-3a6d-4052-937d-cb017338d7b1).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can start by searching wikipedia for various [classification algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) like [k-nearest-neighbour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm), [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) or [neural network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network)

Answer (score 2):

I'd also start with K-Nearest-Neighbours - they are most simple - and one can experiment with different data-preprocessings, distance-measures, etc. They also lead to very good (although very very slow) predictions.

Answer (score 2):

If the variable to be predicted is a continuous one, then regression models are the key.
Many regression techniques are there including least squares, polynomial models, ANN and SVM.
Of course, every technique may have its assumption or parameters.

MATLAB is one of the well-documented computing environments.
I would advise visiting the following page of the MATLAB documentation on nonlinear regression:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinear-regression-1.html#btcgzas-1

You may start by using a global search method such as genetic algorithms GAs to tune the parameters of a given polynomial regression model.

For predicting discrete variables, the listed regression models can be applied also given a threshold. Decision trees can be a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) would fit your need. It has regression and is implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like multi variate linear regression would do the job .

Answer (score 0):

Before diving into the code, since you are a beginner, I would suggest you read on the fundamentals and gain a strong hold on that. You needn't read a PhD thesis but at least the basic terminologies in SVMs, Logistic Regression and Neural Networks would be helpful. There is plenty of material on internet via Stanford, Coursera courses and books suggested in other answers.

Even though there is ready made code available for you to use on the internet, the reason why I am saying you need to read the fundamentals is because in a typical classifier such as SVM, Neural Network or even Logistic Regression, there are various parameters that you would be required to tune, and without an understanding of the fundamentals, it would be difficult and confusing to use these packages. I experienced the same when I was a beginner.

With a strong hold on how to handle a skewed data set in SVM, how to tune the parameters of a Logistic regression, and even how to reduce the dimensions of your dataset, it would make your implementation faster and more efficient - that way you can get better accuracy. Otherwise, diving straight into code may make you come back here with some basic questions again. I hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a regression problem, I would suggest you to start with things like logistic or linear regression in Matlab. There are libraries and you can get code all around for it. By this way, first test and find by comparing in-sample error (from data you consider for production) and out-of-sample error (to test your predictions against data that was not considered for making those predictions) the number and order of features and amount of training data you need. If training data is less, use less features or regularization. If number and order of features is very large and difficult to determine, move to neutral networks or SVM(See, if there is an SVM library fo java) and when you have a perfect system in Matlab then deploy it in Java.
As far as I have seen, ML systems require a good bit of manual fine tuning before they become fit for practical use and environments like Matlab/Ocatve are best platforms for this fine tuning.